# Cannot install Apache 2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I tried to install apache2 on ubuntu 16.04 lts by:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
```

And the output says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2-data apache2-utils
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 330 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,718 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-utils amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 [81.8 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2-data all 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 [162 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 apache2 amd64 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9 [86.6 kB]
Fetched 330 kB in 0s (439 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-utils.
(Reading database ... 470444 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-utils_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9_all.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.16) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Rules updated for profile 'Apache Full'
Rules updated for profile 'OpenSSH'
Firewall reloaded
Setting up apache2-utils (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Setting up apache2-data (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Setting up apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9) ...
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-03-02 18:07:41 CET; 5ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 17497 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]:  *
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]: Output of config test was:
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of...d.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis apache2[17497]: The Apache error log may have more i...n.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited,...=1
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 02 18:07:41 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exi...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf is as below

[image]

And I don't know how to use this information:

```
Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Any help on this issue will be appreciated.

Ps. I also tried

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

and the output is as follows:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-03-02 19:36:17 CET; 1min 44s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24739 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]:  *
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]: Output of config test was:
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 21 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf:21: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis apache2[24739]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 02 19:36:17 gervis systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

So I tried looking at /sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf as @steeldriver suggested. Line 21 says:

[image]

is there some problem there?

Comment: The error may be in one of the files *included by* the line (i.e. one of the `.conf` files in the `sites-enabled` directory), rather than in the line itself I think

Comment: I was so blind I didn't see the # on line 24 of /sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf .. thanks for all the help.

Comment: please post the complete squirrelmail.conf as the error saying that Virtualhost tag was not closed like missing `</VirtualHost>`

Comment: It's fixed no? The #on line 24 should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` from line 24 of `/sites-enabled/squirrelmail.conf` file, where the closing tag of `VirtulaHost` is.

Comment: It's line 24 I guess.